# Looking for a suitable formal sentence

Tags: sentence-choice

I am a non-native researcher in the field of education. I want to write the following message in one of my academic reports, but I think it looks slightly casual. Could you please suggest to me a better substitute for the bolded sentence?

> As is already known, student participation in these online classes is
> optional. **Therefore, student participation in these classes is good
> news for schools.** However, this report shows that this participation alone does
> not imply better student engagement in class.

Thank you so much in advance for your valuable comments and answers.

Comment: Hello, user15402571 and welcome to ELL! Unfortunately, questions that ask for error correction or re-writing are off-topic here, so I'm closing this question to new answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is

> Therefore, student participation in these classes is advantageous for schools.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentence as written is formal enough. I would add the word "potentially" in anticipation of the next sentence.

> Therefore, student participation in these classes is potentially good
> news for schools.

If you want a little more formality, use "advantageous" as @PeterJennings suggests.